# Sort in multiple table Match Against

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I'm using query such like this one:

```
SELECT p.name, d.overview
FROM products AS p 
LEFT JOIN descriptions AS d ON p.DescriptionID = d.ID 
WHERE MATCH (p.name) AGAINST ('ram' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0 
OR MATCH (d.overview) AGAINST ('ram' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0;
```

How to make relevant sorting of this results?

I've tried

```
ORDER BY MATCH (p.name) AGAINST ('ram' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR MATCH (d.overview) AGAINST ('ram' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
```

But this does't help coz result's is not sorting according to their relevancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MATCH ... OR MATCH ...
          ^^
```

The `or` makes this a binary expression.  Binary expressions evaluate to true or false.  So you're sorting on whether they match or not.  Because the `where` clause already ensures all rows match, this not not add ordering.

Try to order by an integer expression, like the summed relevancy:

```
ORDER BY
    MATCH (p.name) AGAINST ('ram' IN BOOLEAN MODE) +
    MATCH (d.overview) AGAINST ('ram' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
```

Comment: About second: `Unknown column 'Relevancy' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @Yekver: looks like MySQL isn't quite as flexible as I thought!  I'll remove the 2nd part.

Comment: So, isn't there be two different queries because of OR and + ? Will MySQL optimize WHERE clause and ORDER BY into one query?

Comment: Try it; if it runs faster in a subquery, use the subquery method.  See [Pretending to be a table](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html)